# Any design reason why Mysql doesn't support isolation level pre transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions

From document,

> A user can change the isolation level for a single session or for all
> subsequent connections with the SET TRANSACTION statement. To set the
> server's default isolation level for all connections, use the
> --transaction-isolation option on the command line or in an option file. For detailed information about isolation levels and
> level-setting syntax, see Section 13.3.7, “SET TRANSACTION Statement”.

But it cannot set the isolation level for a specific transaction, any specific reason?

Comment: You can change the session setting immediately before starting any particular transaction. Why isn't that sufficient for your use case?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever What happens when there are two transactions in one session and they want to use different isolation level? While it should be supported in PostgreSQL.

Comment: How would you have two transactions in one session? MySQL doesn't support nested transactions.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I understand a session is a user connection/session. Or it is a transaction==session? So in my understanding, there are many transactions in one user connection

Comment: A session starts when you connect to a server. You can use the same username/password/server several times ("connection settings"), making several connections in parallel, but on a single session, you can send exactly one command, read the result, send the next command. Try the (command line) MySQL client, it makes a single connection - try to get it to do something in parallel. Your specific application/code might hide that a bit from you for convenience, maybe giving you the illusion that you can do several things at once, but for that it would have to (internally) open new sessions.